# Remove dollar sign on export as CSV file on Datatables

Tags: jquery, csv, datatables, export-to-csv

I am having trouble to remove the dollar sign on export as CSV.

I am editing the datatables.min.js file, I know that this is not recommendable but I need this as I have all export on my all modules.

here is the code of the datatables plugin for export button of CSV.

```
  v.ext.buttons.csvHtml5 = {
    bom: !1,
    className: "buttons-csv buttons-html5",
    available: function () {
      return g.FileReader !== w && g.Blob;
    },
    text: function (a) {
      return a.i18n("buttons.csv", "CSV");
    },
    action: function (a, b, d, c) {
      this.processing(!0);
      a = I(b, c).str;
      d = b.buttons.exportInfo(c);
      var f = c.charset;
      c.customize && (a = c.customize(a, c, b));
      !1 !== f
        ? (f || (f = p.characterSet || p.charset), f && (f = ";charset=" + f))
        : (f = "");
      c.bom && (a = "" + a);
      B(new Blob([a], { type: "text/csv" + f }), d.filename, !0);
      this.processing(!1);
    },
    filename: "*",
    extension: ".csv",
    exportOptions: {},
    fieldSeparator: ",",
    fieldBoundary: '"',
    escapeChar: '"',
    charset: null,
    header: !0,
    footer: !1,
  };
```

in this code. How can I customize all columns with dollar sign and remove it on export only?

Answer (score 0):

If your data has $ sign you can keep that as only the number.
Then while initializing the datatable make the change to display for the columns which require a $ sign inside render function.
This way since your data will be numerical, export itself will just take the number.
[Check this out for Reference](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41022/display-different-value-than-actual-data-source-value)

Note: If you can't change the source data then you can probably process it before giving it to the datatables

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to edit the DataTables source code, I suggest you don't use `datatables.min.js`. Instead use the un-minified version of the file (`datatables.js`). That will be much easier to understand.

Having said that, I think this is a really bad idea (as you already seem to know) and I really cannot recommend this approach.

---

It's not difficult to do what you want in each DataTable.

Here is one way (not the only way):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Brftip',
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: [5],
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        return type === 'export' ? data.substring(1) : data;
      }
    }],
    buttons: [{
      text: 'CSV',
      extend: 'csvHtml5',
      name: 'testExport',
      exportOptions: {
        orthogonal: 'export'
      }
    }]
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In this approach, we use a `columnDefs` option to strip the leading `$` from data in the `Salary` column:

```js
columnDefs: [{ 
  targets: [5], 
  render: function (data, type, row) {
    return type === 'export' ? data.substring(1) : data;
  }
}],
```

The leading dollar sign is removed using `data.substring(1)`. You can use whatever logic you need there, if this is not exactly what you want.

Then, tell the export function to use this modified data:

```js
exportOptions: {
  orthogonal: 'export'
}
```

Even if you need to add this to all of your DataTables now, the time may come when you need a DataTable which does not need this - which is one reason to *not* attemmpt to edit the source code. (And also you will have a harder time upgrading DataTables if you have edited the source code.)

Answer (score 0):

**

## How to export full data in a datatable when using a substring to cut the character

**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrKJ6.png)

Before

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYF59.png)

After

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woLPI.png)

Follow this

```
columnDefs: [
                {
                    render: function(data, type) {
                        return type === 'export' ? data.substring(1) : data;
                    }
                },
                
            ],

buttons: [
                {
                    extend: "collection",
                    className: "btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle mx-3",
                    text: '<i class="bx bx-export me-1 mb-1"></i>Export',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: "csv",
                            text: '<i class="bx bx-file me-2"></i>Csv',
                            className: "dropdown-item",
                            exportOptions: {
                                orthogonal: 'export'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: "excel",
                            text: '<i class="bx bxs-file-export me-2"></i>Excel',
                            className: "dropdown-item",
                            exportOptions: {
                                orthogonal: 'export'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: "copy",
                            text: '<i class="bx bx-copy me-2"></i>Copy',
                            className: "dropdown-item",
                            exportOptions: {
                                orthogonal: 'export'
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ],
```

Thank you from the web developer in Cambodia.